# Square Point of Sale not reading correct dollar amount

Tags: javascript, html, square, square-connect

I am trying to test out the Web API using the example code from the documentation. I can successfully call the APP with generating any errors, but the dollar amount that I am hard coding into my script is not passing over correct. It seems to be two digits off.

I.E $500 translates to $5

I have tried using the value of a text field as well as hard coding in the value. Same result each time.

I call the code when I click a button on my web form:

```
 <!--- Square CC Processing --->
   <script>  
          document.getElementById("do_square_payment_btn").onclick = function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var amount = $('#payment_amount_mobile').val();
            //var amountFixed = amount.toFixed(2);
            console.log("Amount being passed in on square button click " + amount);
            var dataParameter = {
                "amount_money": {
                    "amount" : '5000' ,
                    "currency_code" : "USD"
                },
                "callback_url" : "https://jaydien.ezservicetrax.com", // Replace this value with your application's callback URL
                "client_id" : "sq0idp-CHLAPYt9s1L594ZZZysDSQ", // Replace this value with your application's ID
                "version": "1.3",
                "notes": "Computer Service",
                "options" : {
                "supported_tender_types" : ["CREDIT_CARD"] //,"CASH","OTHER","SQUARE_GIFT_CARD","CARD_ON_FILE"
                }
            };

            console.log(amount);
            console.log("Square button clicked");
            console.log("square-commerce-v1://payment/create?data=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(dataParameter)));
            location.href = "square-commerce-v1://payment/create?data=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(dataParameter));

            };  


          //window.location = "square-commerce-v1://payment/create?data=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(dataParameter));

    </script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: .............Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working exactly as it's supposed to. Per [the documentation](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-charge):

> Note that you specify the amount in the smallest denomination of the applicable currency. For example, US dollar amounts are specified in cents. See [Working with monetary amounts](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#workingwithmonetaryamounts) for details.

So, a value of `500` for USD represents $5.

Comment: (You'll find this behavior in most modern payment APIs. It lets everyone avoid the mayhem of [floating point math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).)

Comment: Sorry, but that is confusing. So if I wanted to pass $89.10, how should that look like?

Comment: okay. Then is there an easy way in javascript to remove the decial from from a number? My users are entering in an amount in a text box that I am passing into the script. For example, a user will type in 89.10

Comment: Or I could just multiply by 100 I guess?

Comment: Yep, multiply by 100 is the usual approach.

Comment: (Saves you from an insane over-charging if someone enters `$10.000`. :-p)